# Hiding a div while user is logged in in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

This is my session's controller code

```
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to_target_or_default root_url, :notice => "Logged in successfully."
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login or password."
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

I need a div `id="welcomebuttons"` located in layouts/application.html.erb to display when the user is not in session (logged out) but disappear completely and remain hidden when the user is logged in. I tried adding `javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()` to the `if user` but of course that didn't work.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in application layout

```
<% if session[:user_id].nil? %>
  <div id="welcomebuttons">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using block helper like this (just added them to your `application_helper.rb` and you're good to go):

```
# application_helper.rb
def not_logged_in(&block)
  capture(&block) unless session[:user_id]
end

def logged_in(&block)
  capture(&block) if session[:user_id]
end

#application.html.erb
<div>I'm visible for everyone</div>

<%= logged_in do %>
  <div>I'm only visible if you are logged in</div>
<% end %>

<%= not_logged_in do %>
  <div>I'm only visible unless you are logged in</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You define a current_user method in the application controller:

```
def current_user
# Look up the current user based on user_id in the session cookie:
#TIP: The ||= part ensures this helper doesn't hit the database every time a user hits a web page. It will look it up once, then cache it in the @current_user variable.
#This is called memoization and it helps make our app more efficient and scalable.
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

and then use it as a condition for an if block in your layout:

```
<% if current_user %>
    <div>  <%= "Logged in as #{current_user.email}" %> | <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %> | <%= link_to 'Log Out', logout_path, method: :delete %> </div>
    <% else %>
     <div> <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %> | <%= link_to 'Log In', login_path %> or <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_path %> </div>
    <% end %>
```